# Using PowerShell to add an entry to "PendingFileRenameOperations" without disrupting previous entries

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-registry

In my case, I wanted to use the Registry value at `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager!PendingFileRenameOperations` to delete a file on reboot. I am using PowerShell.
It would be relatively easy to use something like `MoveFile` or any other command-line binary to add the data to the Registry, but I consider it poor form to use third-party tools (even Sysinternals) when native methods are available.

**The Problem**
`PendingFileRenameOperations` only does anything when the entries within it (it is a Multistring object) are suffixed with two NUL characters, shown in Regedit's binary viewer as `.. ..`. Adding the information normally via PowerShell doesn't work and adding binary data, while possible, would clear out any existing data in the value owing to PowerShell's (certainly PowerShell 2.0's) lack of ability to pull a Registry MultiString object's binary data.

**The Question**
Is it possible to use native methods on a PS2.0 machine to *add* entries to `PendingFileRenameOperations` in such a way that the OS actually acknowledges them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use the following PowerShell code:

```
new-ItemProperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name "PendingFileRenameOperations" -Value $($((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).PendingFileRenameOperations) + "\??\C:\file.exe`0`0") -type MultiString -Force | Out-Null
```

What we're doing here:

- Making a new item of MultiString type (using `set-itemproperty` doesn't work for whatever reason)
- Setting, as its primary value, the data that was in that Registry value to begin with (if anything)
- Adding the normal `\??\C:\File.exe`, which in this case is `\??\` + the file path of the file to delete
- Adding two NUL bytes ( `` `0`0 `` in PowerShell) to the end of the string

This will ensure the file is deleted on next reboot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use .NET from Powershell, for example:

```
Add-Type @"
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class PFRO
{
    public enum MoveFileFlags
    {
        MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING           = 0x00000001,
        MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED               = 0x00000002,
        MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT         = 0x00000004,
        MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH              = 0x00000008,
        MOVEFILE_CREATE_HARDLINK            = 0x00000010,
        MOVEFILE_FAIL_IF_NOT_TRACKABLE      = 0x00000020
    }
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName, MoveFileFlags dwFlags);

    public static bool MarkFileForDelete (string srcfile)
    {
        bool brc = false;
        brc = MoveFileEx(srcfile, null, MoveFileFlags.MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT);
        return brc;
    }
}
"@

$FullName = "C:\toolsde.txt"

if([PFRO]::MarkFileForDelete($FullName))
{
    write-host $FullName "will be deleted on next boot"
}
else
{
    write-host $FullName "will not be deleted on next boot"
}
```

Additionally, I believe PendingFileRenameOperations2 is also a registry value processed by the Windows Session Manager at boot. I suspect you could use that for your purposes without the need to touch PendingFileRenameOperations. Might be worth a test.

Comment: This is really slick code, thanks. Why would I favour PFRO2 over PFRO though? Just because it's less likely anything else would have used it?

Comment: That’s what I thought. I assume when calling the MoveFile API, which most apps would do to populate the reg value indirectly it fills the default pendingfilerenameoperations reg value. I’m not sure if the other one is just overflow? If you use Process Monitor to capture a boot trace you can see smss.exe look for both.